# Capturing HTML tag properties as objecct properties in QTP

Tags: qtp

I have the following HTML tag, which QTP correctly identifies as a `WebEdit` object:

```
<input style="width: 228px;" aria-describedby="x-auto-0" _id="Tenant" name=""
tabindex="1" id="x-auto-23-input" class="x-form-field x-form-text x-form-invalid"
type="text">
```

How do I get the `_id` property from the HTML tag into an object property in QTP? I've used the Object Identification dialog to add both `_id` and `html _id` properties to the `WebEdit` class. However neither are filled in when I use either the Object Spy or the Recorder.

Note that the page being tested contains a number of these text inputs, each with a blank `name` but descriptive `_id`. I'm trying to get the `_id` into a property of WebEdit so I can refer to a particular text box by `Browser("Browser").Page("Page"),WebEdit("_id:=Tenant")`.

Answer (score 3):

HTML attributes can be obtained by using the `.Object.GetAttribute()` function. This is particularly useful for obtaining non-standard attributes (i.e., "_id").

The attribute "id" aligns with the Runtime Object Property "html id", so that can be obtained using `GetROProperty()` or the above method.

An example of using these methods is below:

```
Dim objUI    
Set objUI = Browser("Browser").Page("Page").WebEdit("WebEdit")
Print objUI.GetROProperty("html id")
Print objUI.Object.GetAttribute("id")
Print objUI.Object.GetAttribute("_id")
Set objUI = Nothing
```

To use descriptive programming to access an object, you can use the `attribute/` notation as well as regular expressions. For example:

```
Set objUI = Browser("Browser").Page("Page").WebEdit("attribute/_id:=Tenant", "html id:=x-auto-\d*-input")
```

By default, the .Object methods and properties are not exposed for web elements in the Debug Viewer. It is possible to enhance QTP debugging by registering the Process Debug Manager (PDM) which is included in IE8. This will help you discover additional properties and methods that are available in QTP by using `.Object`. For more information on enhancing debugging in QTP 11, please see the following article:  http://northwaysolutions.com/blog/qtp-11-how-to-enable-enhanced-debugging-features/

Comment: Thank you for the info Brian. I'll definitely make use of the enhanced debugging. However, I really want to get the _id into a searchable `WebEdit` property, and not just be able to use `GetAttribute`. (I've amended my question to clarify this.)

Comment: @JimPfleger Thanks for clarifying. I have updated the answer to be more complete.

Answer (score 2):

You can get objects with custom attributes (properties) with the `attribute/customAttributeKey:=customAttributeValue` identifier. In your case:

```
Set TenantWebEdit = Browser("Browser").Page("Page").WebEdit("attribute/_id:=Tenant")
```

This also allows you to put in more identifiers if you want to to make the description unique:

```
Set TenantWebEdit = Browser("Browser").Page("Page").WebEdit("attribute/_id:=Tenant", "class:=.*x-form-text.*")
```

Comment: With QTP11 the `attribute/_id:=Tenant` syntax did not find any objects. Is there something more that I need to do for this to work? I know it's collecting the attributes because @BrianJM's `objUI.Object.GetAttribute("_id")` gives `Tenant`.

Comment: @JimPfleger Do you have multiple objects with the attribute "_id" = "Tenant? If so, you will need to further define the descriptive programming to be unique (or use the ChildObjects() method with a description object).

Comment: No `_id` is a unique identifier. I don't know why they didn't just put it in `name`.

Comment: This "attribute/" trick does not work for Java GUI components, right?

Comment: @TheBlastOne I suspect it is a feature for Web components, so it would not work for Java I think.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's the *right* way to do this, but I was able to hack up what I needed by loading all of the `WebEdit` objects into a `Dictionary` keyed on their `_id`.

```
Dim WebEdit_desc
Set WebEdit_desc = Description.Create
WebEdit_desc("micClass").value = "WebEdit"

Dim WebEdits
Set WebEdits = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

Dim WebEdit_list
Set WebEdit_list = Browser("Browse Catalog").Page("Add Tenant").ChildObjects(WebEdit_desc)
Dim i
For i = 0 to WebEdit_list.Count() - 1
    If NOT IsNull(WebEdit_list(i).Object.GetAttribute("_id")) Then
        WebEdits.Add WebEdit_list(i).Object.GetAttribute("_id"), WebEdit_list(i)
    End If
Next
Set WebEdit_list = Nothing

WebEdits.Item("Tenant").Set DataTable("Tenant", dtLocalSheet)
```

Answer (score 0):

To extract the **lang** property from Browser document

`Msgbox browser("creationtime:=0").Page("index:=0").GetROProperty("attribute/lang")`

Comment: can you explain your answer?

Comment: @eirenaios this uses the dom property
It checks in the object dom,and returns the lang property value from the dom,
similarly you can use .GetroProperty("attribute/id") or .GetroProperty("attribute/UniqueID")
to get unique id of the object

Comment: It extracts the lang property from Browser document element..Browser("creationtime:=0").Page("index:=0").Object.documentElement.lang

Comment: Pleas edit the question and add this explanation into it so users can understand it better.