# Is it possible play a video and record the timestamp in UFT?

Tags: testing, automation, hp-uft, microfocus

I'm new to automation testing and UFT. I'm trying to play a video and record its timestamp through automation in UFT one. Please let me know if its possible, if so, how?
I'm testing on a Web application

Answer (score 0):

UFT has support the the `<video>` HTML tag.

It supports basic operations such as [Play](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/uft/en/15.0-15.0.2/UFT_Help/Subsystems/OMRHelp/Content/Web/WEBPACKAGELib%7EWebVideo.html#Play) and [Pause](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/uft/en/15.0-15.0.2/UFT_Help/Subsystems/OMRHelp/Content/Web/WEBPACKAGELib%7EWebVideo.html#Pause). You can also use `GetROProperty` to get [properties like `duration` and `current time`](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/uft/en/15.0-15.0.2/UFT_Help/Subsystems/OMRHelp/Content/Web/Web_WebVideo_Properties.htm).

If your application uses a non-standard video container then UFT does not support it out of the box, you'll have to examine the control to see how to extract the data. This is more work but it should be possible (worst case you'll have to use [`attribute/` properties](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15667443/3848)).