# Clicking a Webbutton which is the Child of a Webelement using Microsotf UFT

Tags: automated-tests, hp-uft, uft14, uft-api

I'm currently working on developing a testautomatisation strategy for a web-client. On this web-client all web-elements have a data-testid which is used to identify the object.
Unfortunately in some cases the data-testid is not unique, so clear identification of the object is not possible, I cannot change those data-testids.
So I try to write a component which identifies a webelement based on a data-testid and then presses the button which is a child of that element.
Unfortunately my code doesn't work, becausse UFT cannot identify my object, I'm unfortunately not able to find the solution by myself.
This is how the HTML of the element looks like:
[image: HTML code of the specific part]

I want to find the Webelement with the data-testid "Orderbeleg_Segmentumbuchung" and then click its child withe the data-testid "add:b".

This is the code I wrote:

```
Option Explicit

Dim bcName
bcName = "Webbuttonclick_add"
'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 

Dim pDoit, pParent, var, debug1
pParent = Parameter("parent")
pDoit = CBool(evalVarAndOffset(Parameter("doit")))
var = "data-testid:= .*" & pParent &".*"

If pDoit = True Then
   Browser("index:=0").Page("index:=0").WebElement(var).Click
   If Browser("index:=0").Page("index:=0").WebElement(var).exist(1) Then
        Browser("index:=0").Page("index:=0").WebElement(var).ChildItem("data-testid:= 
        add:b").Click
        wait 1
   End If
End If

SQS_ActionFinish
```

var is the data-testid of the parent-element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of things I see from reading the question (I didn't actually try to run the code so check to see if I'm right).

- You're using `data-testid` as a test object property. I don't think this should work since UFT doesn't define this property. Try `attribute/data-testid` ([further reading](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15667443/3848)).
- You don't need to use `ChildItem` you can nest the `WebElement` directly under the `var` element. You can use a [`WebElement` as a container](https://lanzkron.wordpress.com/2018/10/07/understanding-the-web-test-object-model-in-hp-unified-functional-testing-uft/#Element) even though UFT doesn't do it by default. In fact [`ChildItem`](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/uft/en/2021-2021_R1/UFT_Help/Subsystems/OMRHelp/Content/Web/WEBPACKAGELib%7EWebTable.html#ChildItem) is a `Table` specific method and not applicable here, if you mean [`ChildObjects`](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/uft/en/2021-2021_R1/UFT_Help/Subsystems/OMRHelp/Content/Common_Methods_and_Properties/Common_Methods_and_Properties.html#ChildObjects) then the parameter should be a `Description` object and not a string with the description inline.
- In `var` there's a space before the first `.*`, is that intentional?

To summarise my comments, try this:

`Browser("index:=0").Page("index:=0").WebElement("attribute/data-testid:=.*"&pParent&".*").WebElement("attribute/data-testid:=add:b").Click`

Comment: Thank you that worked! And no the space was not intentional